# How to generate the xcode project of static libs for IOS using Cmake?

Tags: ios, xcode, cmake

I'm trying generate the Xcode project of ASSIMP using Cmake. I know there is already one in it's workspace folder. And I just trying to generate myself. I tried to write the cmakelist.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(assimp)

set(CMAKE_XCODE_EFFECTIVE_PLATFORMS "-iphoneos;-iphonesimulator")
set(CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT iphoneos5.1)
set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT))

add_subdirectory(assimp)
```

then i ran this command:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "$0")"/assimp
if [ ! -d xcode ]
then
    mkdir xcode
fi
cd xcode
cmake -G Xcode ../.. -DINSTALL_LIBS=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../.. -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DBUILD_ASSIMP_TOOLS:BOOL=OFF -DENABLE_BOOST_WORKAROUND=ON

# Device or simulator
xcodebuild -target install -configuration Release
```

it generates the Xcode project but in products is libassimp.dylib and got the "target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.library.dynamic', but there's no such product type for the 'iphoneos' platform" error.

How to change the 'com.apple.product-type.library.dynamic' to static? I had set -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF but it didn't work.

I searched the web and can't find what is causing the problem.

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Oh, please forgive my negligent, in cmakelist.txt at /code/ directory there is a line:

    ADD_LIBRARY( assimp SHARED

just change the SHARED to STATIC, it can be build on IOS platform now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

in cmakelist.txt at /code/ directory there is a line: ADD_LIBRARY( assimp SHARED just change the SHARED to STATIC

the cmakelist i'm using:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.6)

project(assimp)

# Set the Base SDK (only change the SDKVER value, if for instance, you are building for iOS 5.0):
set(SDKVER "5.1")
set(DEVROOT "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer")
set(SDKROOT "${DEVROOT}/SDKs/iPhoneOS${SDKVER}.sdk")
if(EXISTS ${SDKROOT})
    set(CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT "${SDKROOT}")
else()
    message("Warning, iOS Base SDK path not found: " ${SDKROOT})
endif()

# Will resolve to "Standard (armv6 armv7)" on Xcode 4.0.2 and to "Standard (armv7)" on Xcode 4.2:
set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES "$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)")

# seamless toggle between device and simulator
set(CMAKE_XCODE_EFFECTIVE_PLATFORMS "-iphoneos;-iphonesimulator")

include_directories(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

add_subdirectory(assimp)
```